# Não aparece o nome todo

Tags: c, c++

Na linguagem C como poderei mostrar o nome todo quando é pedido para introduzir o nome do utilizador, penso que não esteja correcto a definição do char, o meu código é este:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char nome[100];
fflush(stdin);
int idade;// para garantir que o inteiro utilza 2Bytes
int montdep;// Inteiro utiliza 4Bytes
long int numconta;// para garantir que inteiro utiliza sempre 4Bytes

printf("Introduza o seu nome:\n");
scanf("%s %s",nome);
    printf("Introduza a sua idade:\n");
    scanf("%d",&idade);

    if(idade<=-1)
    {
        printf("Não se aceita valores negativos\nReinicie programa");
    }  
    else
    {
        printf("Introduza o valor a depositar:\n");
        scanf("%d",&montdep);
        printf("Introduza o numero de conta :\n");
        scanf("%ld",&numconta);  
        printf("%s de %d anos, depositou %d€ na conta %ld",nome,idade,montdep,numconta);
    }    
}
```

e o resultado é este

```
Introduza o seu nome:
Jose Esquina
Introduza a sua idade:
25
Introduza o valor a depositar:
2222
Introduza o numero de conta :
22222222222222
Jose de 25 anos, depositou 2222€ na conta 22222222222222
```

Queria que aparecesse o nome todo que foi introduzido e só aparece Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocar `scanf("%s %s"` lê duas palavras para duas variáveis diferentes e não uma só. Se pretende ler várias palavras para uma `string` e terminar apenas no <kbd>Enter</kbd> pode alterar a leitura para:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",nome);
```

Que apenas irá terminar no `\n`. Note que isto pode ser perigoso no entanto se a pessoa que introduz os dados colocar mais dados do que é suposto, neste caso os `100` que definiu.

Se quiser contornar essa situação pode alterar para uma leitura com `fgets`, que já lhe permite especificar o tamanho máximo lido:

```
fgets(nome, 100, stdin);
```

Note no `100` como segundo parâmetro que é a quantidade máxima de carateres a ler. No entanto o `\n` introduzido pelo usuário irá ficar no `nome` também, o qual pode remover fazendo:

```
nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';
```

Documentação para o [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) e para o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/6eMBfO)

Comment: obrigado Isac, funcionou como queria com o scanf que me explicou

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de colocar o & para armazenar o nome, repare que sua linha fica com `,nome`, alterei para => `&nome` e também o caracter char para string mas também pode deixar como char se quiser, e repare que vocÊ tem dois `%s %s` para armazenar uma única variável, isso não é necessário

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
string nome[100];
fflush(stdin);
int idade;// para garantir que o inteiro utilza 2Bytes
int montdep;// Inteiro utiliza 4Bytes
long int numconta;// para garantir que inteiro utiliza sempre 4Bytes

printf("Introduza o seu nome:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", &nome);

printf("Introduza a sua idade:\n");
scanf("%d", &idade);

if(idade<=-1){
    printf("Não se aceita valores negativos\nReinicie programa");
} else {
    printf("Introduza o valor a depositar:\n");
    scanf("%d",&montdep);
    printf("Introduza o numero de conta :\n");
    scanf("%ld",&numconta);  
    printf("%s de %d anos, depositou %d€ na conta %ld",nome, idade, montdep, numconta);
}    
}
```

Comment: dá-me erro na string, não deixa definir assim

Comment: coloca como char novamente e tenta, e posta o erro aqui que aparece ou o resultado exibido